# Deleting old files on large disk resources

Tags: php, linux

I need your advice on how to  perform an efficient clean up of the drive resources.

This is an application based on PHP language. The application runs on various environments, but always operates on one drive, which can have different capacities at its disposal. The average drive's size is 2 TB.

In 90% of the cases files are processed by PHP applications. The remaining 10% of cases relates to external acitvities, like for example - placing files via FTP.

I need to prepare a crontab program that will check all files once a day and delete those files, that are older than the specified time. This time has to be defined by the user, e.g. files older than a year should be removed.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
user
    Order type 1
        Order number
            files to check
        Order number
            files to check
        ...
    Order type 2
        Order number
            files to check
        ...
    Order type 3
        Order number 
            files to check
        ...
    Order type 4
        Order number
            files to check
        ...
    Order type 5
        Order number
            files to check
        ...
...
```

It can be assumed, that there are 5k users in the system on average. Each of them has made many different types of orders, as presented above.
The files are not large. On average, they have 10 MB.

I am currently analyzing this topic using PHP, but it works very very slow. In fact, this is not usable for the users :(

Do you have any idea how to optimize such tasks? How do you deal with such amount of processed data?

EDIT:
The user can manually invoke file deletion actions. Before deleting them, he should see a list of files that will be covered.
So there are two triggers for this operation: crontab and user

Comment: I'd expect a bash script would be far more efficient than using PHP

Comment: Yes, it is faster but it still takes a long time :(

Comment: How slow do you mean exactly? And why is it a problem for users, if it runs as a Cron job in the background? Does it slow the server down in some way? I mean perhaps you need to upgrade something in your server, or perhaps your script is inefficient. Without seeing either system specs or the script, or knowing the precise volumes of data involved, or any timing data from the script it's very difficult to diagnose a specific problem

Comment: Each application is assembled at the client on the server so that each server is different. One is slow and the other is fast. Never the same.

The important thing (which I missed to mention) is that I also need to have a list of files that will be deleted. This is a customer requirement.

So the nighttime cron operation may not be a problem. I have a problem when I have to show the user what will be removed. A kind of operation report / log.

Comment: Or maybe there is an option to index files so that passing them becomes acceptable? I will add that the topic is to be a system functionality and not a system error. I'm just looking for a sensible solution to this problem.

Comment: I think you should add those details to your question, they are important. You can use the "edit" button at the bottom of your question to update it.

Comment: Anyway you still haven't really answered my questions fully - How slow do you mean exactly? What speed would be considered acceptable? What volume of files is generally being searched? Does it get slower in a linear fashion the more files are being searched, or exponentially, or something else? What does the script look like currently? Have you tried to debug parts of it to identify any specific slow areas?

Comment: PS. I edited the content of the question and added two important sentences.

Answering your question is when a user manually launches delete actions wanting to see what will be deleted, e.g. 15 minutes of waiting for an answer, that's a lot.
When crontab starts it, there is no problem. The acceptable time for the user is max 5 minutes to prepare a list of files to delete.
I checked that there are on average 350k files to check.

Comment: Currently my code is based on PHP. During debugging, it turns out that the bottleneck is the recursive reading of files from disk. Takes up most of the time.
I claimed that the script may work slowly because when I was counting the number of files it was 10 minutes for one client and 25 minutes for another, and I only did: find / dir_name | wc -l